# Finding base for a subspace of cubic polynomials with derivative equal to zero in a specific point

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

$U \leq P_3(\mathbb{R}), \\ U = \{P_3(\mathbb{R}): p^{\prime}(5) = 0\}$

I decided to follow a similar method to finding bases for polynomials with a specific root. (Writing the constant as a sum of the other coefficients, substituting and writing the polynomial as a linear combination of the coefficients and then proving that they are linearly independent.)

However, when I do that here, I attain a linear combination of 2 vectors but I'm assuming that $U$ should have a dimension equal to 3. This is what I'm doing:

$p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \\ p^{\prime}(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \\ 0 = p^{\prime}(5) = 3\times 5^2a + 2\times 5b + c = 0 \\ c = -15a -10b \\ p(x) = a(x^3 - 15x) + b(x^2 - 10x) + c \\ S = \{x^3 - 15x, x^2 - 10x, 1\}$

But I'm not too sure of this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost correct.

Firstly, $3\cdot 5^2=75$ not $15$. 
And secondly, you wrote $c$ in the final form of $p(x)$ in place of $d$.

Otherwise, it's fine.